# how to Reference aliased column to another column of a temporary table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on an Excel sheet based algorithm and trying to convert the logic in SQL. There is a need in my SQL logic where I need to create a temporary Table and I am stuck in referencing one aliased column in another aliased column of that table. It looks something like this-

```
INSERT INTO @tbl_CensusTable AS CST
SELECT CS.gender, CS.salary, CS.birthday, CS.Age,
    (some calculation) AS 'Column_5', (Some calculation * CST.Column_5) AS Column_6 
From @tbl_tempTable CS
```

Am I writing the SQL statement correct? Can I reference Column_5 in Column_6 the way I have used in the above example?

Comment: To avoid repeating the expression you need to use either a derived table or a table expression. And you can't alias the inserted table because you're inserting new rows and there's no data yet to refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO @tbl_CensusTable
SELECT CS.gender, 
    CS.salary, 
    CS.birthday, 
    CS.Age,
    (Col5 calculation) AS 'Column_5', 
    ((Some calculation) * (Col5 calculation)) AS Column_6 
From @tbl_tempTable as CS
```

This should work as well:

```
WITH CTE as (
    SELECT CS.gender, 
        CS.salary, 
        CS.birthday, 
        CS.Age,
        (Col5 calculation) AS 'Column_5'
    From @tbl_tempTable as CS
)

INSERT INTO @tbl_CensusTable
    SELECT CS.gender, 
        CS.salary, 
        CS.birthday, 
        CS.Age,
        Column_5, 
        ((SomeCalculation) * Column_5) AS Column_6 
    From CTE as CS
```

Comment: Hi, Since the calculation of Column_5 is very big I don't want to repeat the same in column_6. Is there any way I can reference the column_5?

Comment: Please see the edit. That should work for what you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO @tbl_CensusTable (<good practice to list the columns here>)
SELECT
    CS.gender, CS.salary, CS.birthday, CS.Age,
    CS.Column_5,
    <another calculation> * CS.Column_5 AS Column_6
FROM
    (SELECT *, <some calculation> AS Column_5 FROM @tbl_tempTable) AS CS
```

or

```
;WITH CS AS (
    SELECT *, <some calculation> AS Column_5 
    FROM @tbl_tempTable
)
INSERT INTO @tbl_CensusTable (<good practice to list the columns here>)
SELECT
    CS.gender, CS.salary, CS.birthday, CS.Age, 
    CS.Column_5,
    <another calculation> * CS.Column_5 AS Column_6
FROM CS
```

Answer (score 0):

Try abusing the table valued constructor:

```
select One.v + Two.v as Three 
from (values(1)) One (v)
cross apply (values(2)) Two (v)
```